# Question about Python String: q12 = "4 % 2 = " + (4 % 2)). How can I fix this?

Tags: python, string

I'm taking a Python intro course and couldn't solve this problem.

> Make this string correct and store it in a variable named 'q12'.
>
> ```
> q12 = "4 % 2 = " + (4 % 2))
> ```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you being asked to fix the line to allow it to execute? What type of variable is supposed to be stored in q12?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: `q12 = "4 % 2 = " + str(4 % 2)`

Comment: You cannot ask us to do your homework for you.  You need to make a good faith attempt to solve it yourself and then come to us if it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). What have you already tried? Do you at least know how to fix the syntax error? Do you know [how to convert a number to a string](/q/961632/4518341)? Or, even better, have you learned f-strings? If you want more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, the simplest is to use the f-format, you put f before
the string and curly braces around expresions:

```
>>> def q( m, n): return f"{m} % {n} = {m%n}"
...
>>> q( 53, 22)
'53 % 22 = 9'
```